# What are the average response times for data extension upsert calls using the SOAP API?

Tags: marketing-cloud, soap-api

What are your average response times for basic data extension upsert calls using the ExactTarget SOAP API?

We are seeing average response times of > 2 s for what seem to be simple operations, and are trying to diagnose whether this is normal or an issue in our codebase.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, "it depends" is the only answer I can give you.  Number of rows to upsert, number of columns in the DE, load on the servers, time of day, all cause this to vary wildly.  So the issue could be on your end... or maybe not.  Sorry there isn't a better answer.

Comment: Hi Timothy,
Thanks for answering. We're looking at tiny bits of data - one row per call (data for a single user), way less that 1kb total size, fewer than 10 columns. Time of day is generally East Coast business hours, but we don't see fluctuations in averages around the clock - they're ALL slow.
Does that help?